# Unclear SQLFLUFF lint violation: AM06 "ambiguous column reference": 'GROUP BY/ORDER BY' error

Tags: jinja2, dbt, sqlfluff

In this code:

```
SELECT
    kgi.ingredient_id,
    STRING_AGG(val, ', ') AS aka
FROM {{ ref('stg_bq_kg__ingredients') }} AS kgi,
    UNNEST(synonyms) AS synonym,
    UNNEST(synonym.values) AS val
GROUP BY kgi.ingredient_id
```

I get `L:   7 | P:   1 | AM06 | Inconsistent column references in 'GROUP BY/ORDER BY' clauses.                        | [ambiguous.column_references]` but I am not quite sure why since the column is being referenced clearly.

Note I am using dbt_templater in my `.sqlfluff`.

Comment: There's also a similar post here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77186734/sqlfluff-am06-inconsistent-column-references-in-group-by-order-by-clauses-wh. But none of the asnwers are useful.

Comment: Isn't _"Always use table aliases when referencing columns, especially when joining multiple tables that might have columns with the same names. This way, you ensure clarity and avoid ambiguity"_ your issue? I guess `UNNEST(synonyms) AS synonym,` should be `UNNEST(kgi.synonyms) AS synonym,`.

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε thanks for your reply. I just tried that but still to no avail. The error is pointing to the `group by`.